# Move-Item from sub folder to second subfolder using variable destination

Tags: powershell

I'd like to move all the files in multiple folders into a subfolder within those folders.

So from `C:\Desktop\Folder` to `C:\Desktop\Folder\cv`.

I'm having difficulty targeting the correct destination, so far I've tried:

```
Get-ChildItem *cv -Recurse -Exclude "cv" | Move-Item -Destination {"C:\Desktop\$($_.Name)\cv"}
```

I'm using Windows PowerShell.

EDIT: For those interested I've found a way to do this using CMD:

```
FOR /D %G IN ("*cv") DO robocopy /move "%~G" "%~G\cv" "*"
```

I'd still like to know how to do this using PowerShell, though.

Comment: `$_.Name` or `$PSItem.Name` is the correct way to refer to the current variable in the pipeline

Comment: `... | Move-Item -Destination { "C:\Desktop\$($_.Name)\$($_.Name)" }`. Note the curly brackets.

Comment: Thanks, PowerShell seems to search for those locations now, though I'm now getting a 'Could not find a part of the path' error

Comment: `Move-Item` doesn't create missing folders. `robocopy` does.

Comment: http://ss64.com/ps/move-item.html, says it does with `-Force`

Comment: The folders do exist, and don't need to be created, so that should be okay. Thanks, I tried `-Force` and it seems like it needs a definitive destination rather than a variable one, maybe I need a loop?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Looks to me like ss64 is wrong about that. According to the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item) the parameter `-Force` only suppresses confirmation prompts, and when I just tested it I got the same "could not find part of the path" error with or without `-Force`.

Comment: that would explain why it didn't work for me ^) @AnsgarWiechers